# Google docs API to support 3rd-party storage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

According to [Edit files on 3rd-party storage systems](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9164215?hl=en) article it is possible to edit Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides (Google files) stored on 3rd-party storage systems, such as Box.

Are there public API to provide a possibility to introduce an integration with extra 3rd party storage system (like it is done for example in Box for G Suite native integration, i.e. a file is automatically saved in Box instead of Drive)? Does it require business or enterprise G Suite account?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't Google Support, even if they try to tell you it is. Only people who work at Google can reliably tell you what Google is planning to do.

Answer (score -1):

You could build your own integration with the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to transfer content into and out of Google Drive, assuming you're comfortable with exporting and importing that content as traditional Office docs rather than Google's format.

If you'd like to use it with an arbitrary 3rd party storage system, one way is to build your own app that integrates with both Google and that storage system to allow you to transfer content between them.

Neither of these approaches require your Google account to specifically be a Business or Enterprise account. With both approaches, the data is actually saved within Google Drive but then synced to the other storage platform as well behind the scenes. If that is acceptable, then these solutions might meet your requirements.

Tools like [Kloudless](https://kloudless.com) let you connect to several different cloud storage SaaS apps and protocols with a single implementation. (Disclosure: I'm the CTO). Check out Kloudless' unified [Storage API docs](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/v1/storage) and the Kloudless [File Explorer](https://github.com/kloudless/file-explorer/) to prompt users to pick files to sync.

Comment: Thank you, @vinod , for the info. Yes, it is possible to transfer files back and forth between storage. What I am searching is a possibility to Save files on third party storage instead of Google Drive.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yeah that doesn't seem possible without either having the third-party storage natively integrate Google Drive or syncing the files to Google Drive in some manner.